# how to refine jq output

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, jq

I have a json file. A simple example looks like:

```
[
{
  "host": "a.com",
  "ip": "1.2.2.3",
  "port": 8,
  "name":"xyz"
},
{
  "host": "b.com",
  "ip": "2.5.0.4",
  "port": 3,
  "name":"xyz"

},
{
  "host": "c.com",
  "ip": "9.17.6.7",
  "port": 4,
  "name":"xyz"
}
]
```

I want to extract the "host" and "ip" value and add them in a comma separated values file. Each record in a line as follows:

```
a.com,1.2.2.3
b.com,2.5.0.4
c.com,9.17.6.7
```

I installed jq library to parse the json file. I executed this command:

```
cat test.json | jq '.[] | {host: .host, ip: .ip}'
```

The output I get is as the following:

```
{
  "host": "a.com",
  "ip": "1.2.2.3"
}
{
  "host": "b.com",
  "ip": "2.5.0.4"
}
{
  "host": "c.com",
  "ip": "9.17.6.7"
}
```

Is there any way I can extract the output as I want? This output that jq produced require additional script to parse it and save the values as I want in csv format, one item in a line.

Comment: Doesn't the `@csv` operator do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1):

To remove quotes:

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | [ .host, .ip ] | @csv' | sed 's/"//g'
a.com,1.2.2.3
b.com,2.5.0.4
c.com,9.17.6.7
```

If using OS X, use Homebrew to install GNU `sed`.

Comment: Using sed like this will undoubtedly be acceptable in this case, but in general it could produce incorrect results. In general, if one wants CSV, it is best to use @csv without post-processing, but if one is certain the values do not contain commas or double-quotes, it might be acceptable to use jq’s string interpolation to avoid the quotation marks: "\(.host),\(.ip)"

Comment: Fair comment. I just figured that hostnames and Internet addresses will not contain quotes per RFC 952, so this should be safe to do. When post-processing other strings, caution should be applied, for sure. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952

Comment: @peak This produces the format I want: `jq -r '.[0] | "\(.host),\(.ip)"'`. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@csv` format to produce CSV output from an array of the values.

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | [.host, .ip] | @csv'
```

The `-r` option is needed to get raw output rather than JSON, which would wrap an extra set of quotes around the result and escape the quotes that surround each field.